# C# - Strange ToolStripMenu behaviour

Tags: c#, toolstrip

I have a ToolStripMenu that has a number of sub menus.  At any given time ay of the sub menus may be disabled, depending upon the current state of the program.

I have an issue with a particular menu item.  I have this menu item disabled, so that the sub-menu does not show on mousehover.  It works as expected if I simply hover my mouse over the item, the sub-menu does not appear.  If, however, I hover my mouse over any of the other enabled menu items and have their sub menu appear, then immediately hover the mouse over the disable menu item, the disabled sub-menu will appear, even though this item is still disabled.  The menu-item is greyed out as you would expect.

The menu item is never explicitly enabled anywhere within the code.  Does anybody have any ideas on this?

Comment: Why do not just hide MenuItem which now is disabled ?

Comment: @Tigran - Good idea, it would probably make more sense.  I'd still like to know why the above is acting like it is, if anybody knows.  Thanks.